# C# GTK# MenuBar isn't displaying

Tags: c#, gtk#

I am trying to learn GTK# (obviously in C#). I am using Ubuntu and I compile with mono. I want to create a MenuBar and add some Menu, and MenuItem to it.
When I compile, all is OK but my menu isn't displaying.

```
public MainWindow() : base("LayText")
{
    SetDefaultSize(800, 600);
    SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);
    DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit(); };

    this.InitializeComponent();

    ShowAll();
}

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.m_new = new MenuItem("Nouveau fichier");
    this.m_open = new MenuItem("Ouvrir fichier");
    this.m_exit = new MenuItem("Quitter");

    this.file = new Menu();
    this.file.Append(this.m_new);
    this.file.Append(this.m_open);
    this.file.Append(this.m_exit);

    this.menu_file = new MenuItem("Fichier");
    this.menu_file.Submenu = this.file;

    this.menu_bar = new MenuBar();
    this.menu_bar.Append(this.menu_file);

    this.vbox_princ = new VBox(false, 2);
    this.vbox_princ.PackStart(this.menu_bar, false, false, 0);

    this.Add(this.vbox_princ);
}
```

When I compile this code I am getting the window but without the menu I've set.

[Screenshot of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpD7t.png)

Thanks for helping me.
Layce17

Comment: try to call ShowAll() on the menu

Comment: No isn't working, i've trying on the Menu, the MenuBar and my menu_file Item but no one is working.

Answer (score 0):

The following code (just a modification/completion or yours) works perfectly. I see you are using Ubuntu. Though I don't use it, I think it shows the menu bar in the top status bar. Have you checked that out?

```
using Gtk;

namespace Kk
{
    class MainWindow: Gtk.Window {
        public MainWindow() : base("LayText")
        {
            SetDefaultSize(800, 600);
            SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);
            DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit(); };

            this.InitializeComponent();

            ShowAll();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            var m_new = new MenuItem("Nouveau fichier");
            var m_open = new MenuItem("Ouvrir fichier");
            var m_exit = new MenuItem("Quitter");

            var file = new Menu();
            file.Append(m_new);
            file.Append(m_open);
            file.Append(m_exit);

             var menu_file = new MenuItem("Fichier");
             menu_file.Submenu = file;

             var menu_bar = new MenuBar();
             menu_bar.Append(menu_file);

             var vbox_princ = new VBox(false, 2);
             vbox_princ.PackStart(menu_bar, false, false, 0);

             this.Add(vbox_princ);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.Init();
            new MainWindow();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.